# Roles don't work in Spring Boot Oauth Resource Server

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have been fighting with roles all day long and I can't solve this :(.
My code below:

SecurityConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys;

    public SecurityConfig(RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys) {
        this.rsaKeys = rsaKeys;
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager user() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("wojtek")
                        .password("{noop}password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth
                                .requestMatchers("/token").authenticated()
                                .requestMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeys.publicKey()).privateKey(rsaKeys.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }
}
```

TokenService.class

```
@Service
public class TokenService {

    private final JwtEncoder encoder;

    public TokenService(JwtEncoder encoder) {
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }


    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        System.out.println(scope);

        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("roles", scope)
                .build();

        return encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Principal principal) {
        return "Hello, " + principal.getName() + "!";
    }
}
```

I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I had logged and sent request at "/" and I get 403 Forbidden Error.
I don't have any idea :(.
What is the problem?

```
System.out.println(scope); //prints ROLE_USER
```

Thank you for help!

//EDIT
All fine works!

with

```
.requestMatchers("/").hasAuthority("SCOPE_USER")

User.withUsername("wojtek")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .authorities("USER")
                .build());

JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
        .issuer("self")
        .issuedAt(now)
        .expiresAt(now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
        .subject(authentication.getName())
        .claim("scope", scope)
        .build();
```